# values of $\lambda$for $v(x,t):=u(\lambda x,6t)$ to be another solution of the heat equation?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

Let $Q=\mathbb{R}^n\times (0,\,+\infty)$ and  $u:Q\to\mathbb{R}$ a solution (classical) of the heat equation $\partial_tu-D\Delta{u}=0 $in $Q$, where $D>0$ is an assigned coefficient. Let $v(x,t):=u(\lambda x,6t)$ with $ \lambda\in\mathbb{R}$. How many values of $\lambda$ are there for which the function $v$ is also a solution of the heat equation in  $Q$?

**My try:**

$0=\partial_tv -D\Delta = \partial_t u(\lambda x,6t)-D\Delta u(\lambda x,6t) =6\partial_t u -D\lambda \Delta u$.

So I think I must choose $\lambda = 6$ as the only value.

**However the correct answer should be that there are two values.  How come? What I am doing wrong?**

Comment: My thought is to consider the what the laplacian does on v since you need to take 2 spatial derivatives (chain rule). Are you sure that its a factor of just $\lambda$ in front?

Comment: Yes, I am sure that is the question. I used the chain rule in the second step, so I don't know what am I missing

Comment: oh, I see ,you mean in my solution there must be a $\lambda^2$ I forgot there are two derivatives there